# Multiple chained deferred functions using q in AngularJS stop returning data

Tags: angularjs, q

I am trying to chain together multiple deferred function calls such that the next call gets the results of the previous deferred.resolve. When I chain together more than 2 of these calls, the data stops being returned.

Here is the basic code inside an angular controller:

```
    $scope.runAsync = function() {
        var asyncFn1 = function(data){
            var deferred = $q.defer();

            $timeout(function(){
                console.log("Async fn1 " + data);
                $scope.outputLines.push("Async fn1 " + data);
                deferred.resolve("Async fn1 " + data);
            },1000);

            return deferred.promise;
        }

        var asyncFn2 = function(data){
            var deferred = $q.defer();

            $timeout(function(){
                console.log("Async fn2 " + data);
                $scope.outputLines.push("Async fn2 " + data);
                deferred.resolve("Async fn2 " + data);
            },1000);

            return deferred.promise;
        }

        asyncFn1(1)
        .then(function(data){asyncFn2(data)})
        .then(function(data){asyncFn2(data)})
        .then(function(data){asyncFn2(data)});
    }
```

When I run this I get the following output:

```
Async fn1 1
Async fn2 Async fn1 1
Async fn2 undefined
Async fn2 undefined
```

How can I chain them together so that the third call gets the result from the second call and the fourth gets the result from the third?

I have created a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rhDyL/

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Excerpt taken from the official doc on $q:

> then(successCallback, errorCallback) – regardless of when the promise
>   was or will be resolved or rejected calls one of the success or error
>   callbacks asynchronously as soon as the result is available. The
>   callbacks are called with a single argument the result or rejection
>   reason.
>
> This method returns a new promise which is **resolved or rejected via
>   the return value of the successCallback or errorCallback.**

And for the return value of the successCallack or errorCallback, according to [Domenic's slides](http://www.slideshare.net/domenicdenicola/promises-promises):

> if the return value is a promise then the promise adopts the returned
>   promise's state otherwise the success callback is immediately called
>   with the return value

Based on the definition, your code is missing the `return` keyword. It should be as following:

```
    asyncFn1(1)
    .then(function(data){return asyncFn2(data)})
    .then(function(data){return asyncFn2(data)})
    .then(function(data){return asyncFn2(data)});
```

Comment: Wow.. thanks. I kind of see it now. I'm just confused by the fact that the .then() method returns a new promise, but inside the asyncFn I am returning a promise from the deferred object. It seems like double the number of promises.

Comment: I was in the same position myself not long ago. _Promise & deferred_ does require a bit of learning curve and practice to get used to. Nevertheless, I think it's worth it. It makes managing code execution in the world of async programming much more easier. If you are still not familiar with the topic, I highly recommend [this reading](http://www.slideshare.net/domenicdenicola/promises-promises).

Comment: @tamakisquare - thanks for the response and comment. I think the key point of confusion which is clarified in slide #7 of [domenic's presentation](http://www.slideshare.net/domenicdenicola/promises-promises) is that if the return value is a promise then the promise adopts the returned promise's state otherwise the success callback is immediately called with the return value. Maybe you can modify your answer to reflect that also - to be more complete. Thanks.

Comment: @Amir - Thanks for the suggestion. I'll shall add that to the answer. FYI, You'll earn the privilege to refine/modify others' answers once you reach 2000 points.

Comment: @tamakisquare - great. Thank you. And I'll work towards getting the 2k points. :)