# Promise chaining using then

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise

Does function `c` get invoked before the promise returned from `b` is resolved?

```
function a() {
 var d = $q.defer();
 setTimeout(function() { d.resolve(); }, 10000);
 return d.promise;
}

function b() {
 var d = $q.defer();
 setTimeout(function() { d.resolve(); }, 10000);
 return d.promise;
}

function c() {
 var d = $q.defer();
 setTimeout(function() { d.resolve(); }, 10000);
 return d.promise;
}

a().then(b).then(c);
```

Comment: Can't you add logs within each function to test by yourself?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16071566/multiple-chained-deferred-functions-using-q-in-angularjs-stop-returning-data

Comment: If it hadn't worked that way - promises wouldn't be very useful now would day?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply No. The promise b must be first resolved to execute c.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't. If a function provided to `Promise.then` (which returns promise `A`) returns a `Promise` (promise `B`), `A` waits on `B` to be resolved before resolving itself. ([See documentation.](https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.6/docs/api/ng/service/$q))